# OSGI Spring MVC JSP framework

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, osgi

Is there a way to create a "plug-in" framework for web applications that have these features:

**Seemless for the developer - can use existing technologies**

e.g.

- Spring MVC annotations (e.g. Request Mapping)
- Hibernate / JPA with annotations
- JSP, JSTL, and servlet views

**Seperation - class loading, session, http context**

- e.g. each @RequestMapping is confined to a subset of the "main" URL (e.g. one "plugin" can't hijack the URL request of another "plugin" for example the URL `http://localhost/rootContext/plugin1/action1?param=value` will require a mapping that is relative to the "module" / "plugin" which is "plugin1" and not the root context, so if we have full seperation of http context, I expect the annotation to be `@RequestMapping("action1"...)`
- also Parent Last classloading so each module can have it's own jars etc..
- also protection on the session object to avoid overwriting session keys accedently (and for security)

**Supports plain old JSPs**

- I'd like to have the view tehnology be JSPs, I find them much easier than Freemarker, or Velocity

I thought of Apache Felix, OSGI, Spring-OSGI MVC etc... but still need more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at [Eclipse Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/), possibly the best choice for greenfield projects for the moment which want to include Spring and JSP.